# Choosing ARIMA model in r

Tags: r, arima

I have run an ARIMA model on univariate time series data. I have the below statistical results with the lag differencing at 3. I am not sure which of the model to select to forecast. Any help to choose the order out of the below 2 would be much appreciated.

Note: dataframe d.ratio is with 3rd lag differencing.

[image: p2, d3, q3]

[image: p1, d3, q1]

Comment: I'd pick the one with the smallest AIC; which is the `(2,0,3)` model. See [here](https://otexts.com/fpp3/arima-r.html) for more information.

Comment: Youcan try `auto.arima()` and compare results!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know auto arima exist in R, new to R programming.